# How to make grep command return entire matching line

Tags: linux, bash

How can I make the command `grep -w` show the entire line that contains the match?
I need to force *pattern* to match whole words, but I need to see all of the line.

Here is my command:

```
cat /var/log/message.log | grep -w foobar
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, `grep` shows the whole line for which a match has been found.
For a specific word, I use `grep` directly instead of `cat | grep`.

```
grep -w "foobar" /var/log/messages.log
```

If you do not see any other output, it would mean that there isn't anything else on that line.

Comment: This is correct. It's possible to change this using the `--only-matching` flag to show only the part of a line that matches your pattern (at least it is on GNU grep, I'm unsure about others).

Comment: `-w` only works for whole word matches. e.g., for `foobar`, `grep -w 'foo' ...` will not match

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach (beside -w option) is to do matching whole lines by an appropriate pattern:

```
cat /var/log/message.log | grep -P \^\.\*foobar\.\*\$
```

or case insensitive:

```
cat /var/log/message.log | grep -iP \^\.\*foobar\.\*\$
```

One advantage here is that it could be used file indepndent, like:

```
xauth list | grep -iP \^\.*foobar\.\*\$
```